# How to get all TaskItems for recurring task Outlook (VBA)?

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to get list of all tasks for specific dates. How can I loop in VBA every TaskItem for recurring tasks? For Appointments there is method [.GetOccurence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recurrencepattern.getoccurrence), but it's don't work for tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `GetOccurrence` for the `TaskItem` objects returns an error.

The only workaround is to either expand the recurrence pattern programmatically based on the recurrence properties (task made somewhat easier since there are no exceptions for recurring tasks) or use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) - it's version of [RDOTaskItem](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOTaskItem.htm).`GetRecurrencePattern.GetOccurrence()` works as expected for tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Another way - temporary AppointmentItem

```
Function GetRecTaskDates(dStart As Date, dEnd As Date, objTask As Object)

    Dim objTempApnt As Object
    Dim objTaskPatt As Object
    Dim objTempPatt As Object
    Dim objCurApnt As Object
    Dim dCurDate As Date
    Dim arrResult()
    Dim iCount As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim lRecType As Long

    Set objTempApnt = objTask.Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    objTempApnt.Subject = "temp"

    Set objTempPatt = objTempApnt.GetRecurrencePattern
    Set objTaskPatt = objTask.GetRecurrencePattern

    With objTempPatt
        .RecurrenceType = objTaskPatt.RecurrenceType
        lRecType = .RecurrenceType
        If objTaskPatt.DayOfMonth Then .DayOfMonth = objTaskPatt.DayOfMonth
        If lRecType = 1 Or lRecType = 3 Or lRecType = 6 Then .DayOfWeekMask = objTaskPatt.DayOfWeekMask
        .StartTime = #9:00:00 AM#
        .EndTime = #10:00:00 AM#
        .PatternStartDate = objTaskPatt.PatternStartDate
        If objTaskPatt.Interval Then .Interval = objTaskPatt.Interval
        If objTaskPatt.NoEndDate Then
            .NoEndDate = objTaskPatt.NoEndDate
        Else
            .Occurrences = objTaskPatt.Occurrences
            .PatternEndDate = objTaskPatt.PatternEndDate
        End If
        If lRecType >= 5 Then .MonthOfYear = objTaskPatt.MonthOfYear
        If lRecType = 3 Or lRecType = 6 Then .Instance = objTaskPatt.Instance
    End With

    objTempApnt.Save

    For dCurDate = dStart To dEnd
        On Error Resume Next
        Set objCurApnt = objTempPatt.GetOccurrence(dCurDate + objTempPatt.StartTime)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve arrResult(1 To n)
            arrResult(n) = dCurDate
        End If
        Err.Clear
    Next dCurDate
    On Error GoTo 0

    objTempApnt.ClearRecurrencePattern
    objTempApnt.Delete

    If n > 0 Then GetRecTaskDates = arrResult

End Function
```